# Как избежать рекурсии?

Tags: python, ооп, рекурсия

У меня есть подкласс с дополнительным параметром battery, значение которого может быть в диапазоне от 50 до 100. Хочу, чтобы при инициализации экземпляра при вводе значения не входящего в эти параметры выходило сообщение print о том, что такое значение не допустимо и соответственно устанавливалось значение self.battery=70 по умолчанию. Самый простой способ был сделать проверку в самом инициализаторе init, но я решил применить сеттер, чтобы потом можно было редактировать эту переменную уже после инициализации и и попадать под ту же проверку на вхождение параметра в допустимый диапазон.

Вот мой код

```
class eCar(Car):

def __init__(self, name, model, year, battery=70):
    super().__init__(name, model, year)
    self.battery=70
    
@property
def battery(self):
    return self.battery
@battery.setter
def battery(self, battery):
    if battery>50 and battery<100:
        self.battery=battery
    else:
        print('Некорректный объем батареи. Установлено по умолчанию 70')
        self.battery=70
```

Причина рекурсии ясна - сеттер ссылается сам на себя. Я решил оставить код в таком ввиде, возможно у вас есть идеи как исправить эту ошибку, стоит ли вообще использовать здесь сеттер или лучше воспользоваться методом?

Answer (score 2):

Не называйте одинаково сетер/геттер и атрибут

```
class eCar(Car):
    
    def __init__(self, name, model, year, battery=70):
        super().__init__(name, model, year)
        self.battery = battery
        
    @property
    def battery(self):
        return self.batteryValue

    @battery.setter
    def battery(self, battery):
        if battery>50 and battery<100:
            self.batteryValue=battery
        else:
            print('Некорректный объем батареи. Установлено по умолчанию 70')
            self.batteryValue=70
```

Comment: Опередил )  Но таки лучше/конвенциональнее использовать формально скрытое поле `self._battery`

Comment: Это наверное, даже лучше. Но смысл сильно не менят

Comment: Отлично. Большое спасибо. Можете показать также пример с инкапсуляцией? Не совсем понял как тут его правильно реализовать